# Using Wishlist Member and I need to access a user's status

Tags: plugins, php, array, membership

I am trying to create a default "Membership Alert" page, so if a user's membership has been cancelled, has expired, requires approval or requires confirmation I want to give them a message on this page. I need to get the user's status, and I'm not sure which API function has access to this info, then I want to create conditional arguments based on this info to display the right "alert" message.

I started with this:

`$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
$user_status = wlmapi_get_member_by('user_id', $user_id);
print_r($user_status);`

And tested it with a user I had just cancelled. But the array isn't displaying the info I need.

UPDATE! Here's the solution I came up with:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
$my_levels = wlmapi_get_member_levels($user_id);
$my_levels = json_decode(json_encode($my_levels), true);

foreach ($my_levels as $my_level) :
    $level_id = $my_level['Level_ID'];
    echo '<h2>' . $my_level['Name'] . ':</h2>';
    $member_data = wlmapi_get_level_member_data($level_id, $user_id);
    $member_data = json_decode(json_encode($member_data), true);
    $member_status = $member_data['member']['level']['Status']['0'];

    if($member_status == 'Cancelled') :
        if(get_field('membership_cancelled')) :
            echo '<p>' . the_field('membership_cancelled') . '</p>';
        endif;
    elseif($member_status == 'Expired') :
        if(get_field('membership_expired')) :
            echo '<p>' . the_field('membership_expired') . '</p>';
        endif;
    elseif($member_status == 'For Approval') :
        if(get_field('membership_requires_approval')) :
            echo '<p>' . the_field('membership_requires_approval') . '</p>';
        endif;
    elseif($member_status == 'Pending') :
        if(get_field('membership_requires_confirmation')) :
            echo '<p>' . the_field('membership_requires_confirmation') . '</p>';
        endif;
    else :
        echo '<p>Your membership is active!</p>';
    endif;
endforeach;
```

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution but it works. If anyone has any refinements I would love to learn from them.